# Half-Hot powering the rest of the room's receptacles

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

Here's the situation.

Master Bedroom
Receptacles on 1 Circuit: 7 Receptacles and Master Bathroom (small, only light, fan and 1 other receptacle that is included in the 7)

Over the weekend, I plugged in a laptop charger and heard crackling in another outlet (oops that's not good); immediately unplug the laptop and was going to deal with it in the morning.

Sure enough the outlet was burnt and was shorting (see picture) and I am glad I caught it before any more real damage happens.

[image: Wiring of Burnt Plug]

The old receptacle was set-up that 1 of the outlets was hot and had power the entire time, the other controlled by a switch.

I am replacing the receptacle with a similar type, 125 volt-15 amp. The wires I have are 2 Black (hot), 2 White (neutral), a bare/ground, and 1 Red (hot switch).

When I replaced the old, burnt one receptacle with the new one it is that the red wire/switch is controlling the rest of the room and bathrooms receptacle/power (I don't want that) while the other outlet is either Hot or not depending on which black wire I attached to the Red one. Tried both blacks to the red.

[image: New Receptacle Wiring]

Goal is to have only 1 half of the receptacle be controlled by the switch and then the rest hot and powering the rest of the room/bathroom

Comment: Have you determined whether or not the previous outlet was wired correctly? You've written that the black ones are hot and the red one is switched-hot, but it sounds like the evidence actually shows you that one black wire is always-hot, one black wire is switched-hot, and the red wire is the always-hot wire going to the rest of the room.

Comment: The key to powering only one outlet of the duplex, are the tabs on the side that can be snapped off.  Show us the hot (black) side of the outlet, there will be a tab that must be removed to separate the power to each.

Comment: The old, burnt outlet _should_ have the tab between the two screws broken off on the side that we cannot see in your pic. You'll need to replicate that on the new outlet.

Comment: Note for future reference: the crackling you heard and burns you see on the old outlet are evidence of *arcing* (typically caused by a bad connection between things which *should* be connected), not shorting (typically caused by an unintended connection between things which *should not* be connected).

Comment: I agree with Brhans back stabs are notorious for doing this don’t use backstabs (the push in connectors) or before long the wires will be burned off.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did break the bridge tab on the Hot Side.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't *experiment*, but in this case moving black and red wires around on the hot side shouldn't do any harm. Have you tried both blacks on one screw, and red alone?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have tried the following, sorry if this looks a bit cluster

White 1 = Top Outlet = Black 1/Red 1; Switch on Power in outlet and room
White 2 = Bottom Outlet = Black 2

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have tried the following (ignore the top wasn't done writing)

Top Outlet = Black 1/Red 1; Switch on Power in outlet and room; Switch Off No power in outlet and room
White 2 = Bottom Outlet = Black 2; Switch on Power in outlet and room; Switch off Power in outlet, no power in room

Top Outlet = Black 2/Red 1; Switch on Power in outlet, no power in room; Switch Off Have power in outlet, but not in room
Bottom Outlet = Black 1; Switch on No Power in room or outlet; Switch off No Power in outlet, no power in room

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box please?